# Dialog - unnecessary multiple drawing?

Tags: android, listview, android-7.0-nougat

After upgrade from Lollipop (5.0.2) to Nougat (7.1.2), client reported me a disturbing phenomenon of repeatedly drawed dialog after displaying on the screen. The problem is clearly seen in Dialogs with many controls.

The same application under Lollipop worked correctly:

- the dialogue was displayed quickly (0.5 sec),
- dialog was immediately responsive (0.0 sec after showing)

After switching to Nougat:

- the dialogue is displayed with a delay (2.5 sec)
- after appearing on the screen, you need to wait a few seconds for the responsibility (4.2 sec after show)

In four attached films I present this phenomenon in different situations and Android versions. See the bottom edge of the dialogs:

1. [Lollipop - dialog with ListView](https://youtu.be/oeiGjhCQZrk) - correct
2. [Lollipop - dialog with ScrollView](https://youtu.be/sTrElCn4Pg0) - correct
3. [Nougat - dialog with ListView](https://youtu.be/FrGEwkzw1fI) - incorrect!
4. [Nougat - dialog with ScrollView](https://youtu.be/8RVAFSE11JI) - incorrect!

In the case of a dialog with ListView, under Nougat, **for each element**, the Adapter.getView () method was called up to 36 times! I suppose, it means, that dlalog was painted 36 times.

After some corrections in the layout xml, I was able to reduce the number of Adapter.getView () calls up to 5, but never to 1.

However, under Nougat, in the case of a dialog without ListView, there is still the unsightly effect of "matching" the dialog after it appears on the screen.
Under Lollipop, there is only a one call to Adapter.getView () for each item.

**Please help, how to try eliminate this effect?**

The customer cannot change the Android version to a newer one, because it is a large production and after tests with Nougat, we can no longer afford it.